# How to accept attributes for models that don't have an active record association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm making a simple team allocation app. I have three models - Players, Teams and Rounds. The idea is to have a list of players from which a user can select those who are actually there on the day to play in a round. So far I have the code that takes all the current players in the db and randomly allocates them to a team (the teams are created when a round is created).

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  belongs_to :round
end

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

I've written a function that is called during round create to create and populate teams. That's working fine, but it is just getting the input list of players from `Player.all`.

What I would like is in *rounds/new.html.erb* to have something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for(@players) do |player| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'player_ids[]', player.id, true %>
  <%= player.first_name %> <%= player.surname %>
<% end %>
```

That way on `submit` I can process the array of selected users for this round and only assign those players to a team. I thought about using

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
```

in the rounds model, but it doesn't actually have (or need) an association with the players. Is there a way I can achieve this or something similar? Should I instead setup an action in the players controller that manages the checkbox view/submit and then store the user's selection in session data?

Comment: create `Player.all_selected(params[:player_ids])` - something like that.

Comment: Hei, you can do this very simply with http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes, you don't even need accepts_nested_attributes_for for this. Replace your fields_for block with: `  <%= f.collection_check_boxes : player_ids, Player.all, :id, : first_name %>` and update your accepted params to include `player_ids: []`

Comment: Can you explain the use of `player_ids` as the first argument? I've tried what you suggested @cristian but I get a `undefined method 'player_ids'` error. I'm also not sure how to include the player_ids: array in params. Would it just be `def round_params
      params.require(:round).permit(:name, :player_ids)
    end`

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following code to your form:

```
<% @players.each do |p| %>
  <%= label_tag do %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'players[]', p.id, false %>
    <%= "#{p.first_name} #{p.surname}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then there will be and array of ids in `params[:players]` and then you can use the comment from @iced.

Your model do not have to know anything about how you procured these ids and that is nice due to [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).